# Need help in understanding the code below awk(&&&&) code:

Tags: awk

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
 if (length($0) < 80)
 {
      prefix = "";
       for (i = 1;i<(80-length($0))/2;i++)
          prefix = prefix " ";
        print prefix $0;
    }
else
 {
print;
    }
}
```

Could any one please tell me what exactly the prefix variable is doing in the above code.

Comment: You could try to replace `prefix = prefix " ";` with `prefix = prefix "|";` or something similar and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to just do `{printf "%80s\n", $0}` to have that indentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is to make the incoming text as Centre Aligned text.

1. Read the text
2. Declare a empty string in the variable name prefix
3. Calculate the position where to paste your text is determined by the for loop by prefixing spaces for the same. In this case, we print spaces until we are at the position at  ((80 - length of your string ) /2)
4. Print your string

**Note**: $0 in AWK is your complete string like "I want to test this" where as $1 will be "I" and $2 will be "want", where as in shell it prints your current shell you are working with

Answer (score 1):

It's adding front padding to center the string on the line if it's shorter than the line length but you can do the same thing with just:

```
awk '{ printf "%*s\n",(80+length($0))/2, $0 }'  file
```

Answer (score 0):

It increments `prefix` with blank space to create a line with space in front according to the formula.

```
echo "test" | awk -f script
                                     test
```

Answer (score 0):

it builds an empty string place holder (for left padding), which has length= `(80-length of the line)/2`